# Time user input from first keystroke in R

Tags: r, user-input

Looking to time how long it takes a user to type a message in R from the first keystroke.

I can use functions like `readline()` or `scan()` to get the user input, and I can use the `system.time()` to measure how long it takes for the code to be run:

```
> system.time(readline())
Test Message
   user  system elapsed 
   0.98    0.53   19.55
```

However, these give me the total elapsed time. If  I wait wait 15 seconds before typing, this is reflected in the output of `system.time()`, and not just the time I spent to write the message. (E.g 19.55s = 15s + ~4.5s I used to type the message.)

Looking for this to happen in the console, but also willing to use a separate window if necessary.

Comment: This is a weird question, what do you need it for (as in it isn't exactly clear)? Would using `Sys.time` when the function is called work for time-point zero and capture the time period immediately after (with `Sys.time`) be useful enough? (You can subtract start from end)

Comment: I don't think there is a general way to do this that will always work.  I can think of ways to do it using shiny or gWidgets but I don't think you have the ability to see what's currently typed on the console until it's actually sent.

Comment: @TJGorrie this isn't for anythign practical (at least in my case) just more curiosity. I came across it on this code golf https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/146587/type-the-alphabet-as-fast-as-you-can and noticed there was no R answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently solved this issue using a combination of two packages - `tictoc` and `keypress`.

From `keypress` you can use the `keypress()` function that waits for user input and then outputs the key that was pressed - `keypress()` only works in R on command line and it supports the majority of keys, but not all of them.

To time from a keypress you can write a simple `if` statement that calls the `tic()` function from `tictoc`.

**Example**

When I posted this question I was looking to time how long it would take someone to type the entire lowercase alphabet after hitting the 'a' key.

```
require(tictoc)
require(keypress)

for(i in 1:26){

  a=keypress()

  if(a==letters[1])  tic()
  if(a==letters[26]) toc()

  cat(paste(a))
}

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz6.649 sec elapsed
```

This starts the stopwatch when 'a' is hit, and then stops it when the 'z' key is pressed.