# Is it possible to use R as stopwatch to measure the time elapsed between keystrokes?

Tags: r, user-input, stopwatch

I am developing an R package to measure the behavioural responses of animals toward odour sources. To achieve this I need to be able to record the amount of time (in seconds) that an individual spends in five predetermined zones and how many times they enter each zone.

I am struggling to find any information that suggests R can be used to do what I need, although I'm sure it can!

Essentially I want to assign each zone to a key, which I can press when an individual enters a zone and for R to measure the total amount of time in each zone and the number of times they entered. I have searched extensively on the forum to see whether something similar has been achieved previously and found two relevant threads:

1. [Time user input from first keystroke in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47514592/time-user-input-from-first-keystroke-in-r)
2. [How to allow multiple inputs from user using R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540232/how-to-allow-multiple-inputs-from-user-using-r)

However, neither of these threads fully enable me to measure the required values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Frankly I would do this with python tkinter / pygame or any other general purpose language. Not sure if R is the best language for GUI programs.

Comment: I agree, but unfortunately am restricted to using R as it the most widely used language amongst my colleagues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on the 2 very helpful threads that you linked you could try something like:

```
require(tictoc) #load required package
while(T){       #open infinite while loop
    tic()       #start timer
    input_state=readline("State input: ")  #allow for entry of state
    if(input_state %in% 1:5){    #check if it's acceptable 
        elapsed=toc()            #if it is then end timer and record data
        write.table(cbind(input_state,elapsed$toc-elapsed$tic),'results.txt',col.names=F,row.names=F,quote=F,append=T)
    }else if(input_state=='t'){  #if input is 't' 
        break                    #break out of while loop
    }else if(input_state <1 | input_state > 5 & input_state!='t'){#if input is not and accepted state AND is not 't'
     print('thats not an allowed state- please try another')
     } 
}
```

then to get the number of times that each state was entered you can do:

```
data=read.table('results.txt',stringsAsFactors=F,header=F)
table(data[,1])
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, my computer also doesn't support the `keypress` package so am unable to test it either! I think this is why I have struggled to incorporate the information from the previous threads into useable code. I was hoping that there was an alternative package that could replace `keypress`.

Comment: Sorry I just realised that my answer bypasses a need for that package- so I was able to test it. I had to add a 't' for `terminate` option to let the code know when a 'state' has finished- the data needs to be written to a text file instead of filling a dataframe as `tictoc` seems to do something funny with the `dataframe` object.

Comment: I have tested the code and it works great, but wonder whether it is possible to use the state it enters as the termination key. This would improve the accuracy of the total time spent in each zone as the current code also times the length of time for each 't'. Having to complete 100 rounds of the experiment is also limiting as it usually is done for a set time period of 12 minutes. I really appreciate your help so far, it has really helped me to understand how this could be possible using R.

Comment: redone with a while loop that you can `break` out of if you press 't'. Hope this helps :) . If it does could you upvote my answer thanks.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you so much! Is it possible to user numbers 1 to 5 as the input. I also noticed that if you push an invalid state, for example `z`, it still records the time for this key and as an entrance - can this be prevented? I just tried to upvote your answer but received the following message: _Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score_. Again, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: modified my answer- no need to 'upvote'- I should have said click the 'tick' below the 'upvote' option to state that the answer works. Observe how I made it possible for the states to be `1:5`- I used `if(input_state %in% 1:5)` instead of `letters[1:5]`. Then to stop the recording of incorrect states- I put the `write.table` command inside the `if in 1 to 5` statement to make sure only correct states are recorded. To give an error message after receiving an incorrect input: the final if statement is activated when input <1 OR >5 AND NOT equal to 't'.

Comment: Apologies for the misunderstanding, I have now clicked the 'tick'! This now works exactly as I wanted, I really appreciate your help. One final question with regards to `write.table`: is it possible to give the columns headings such as 'time' and 'input_state'? Also, is it possible to overwrite the table completely as I would want to keep each experiment seperate and not add extra data into the same file. Many thanks again :)

Comment: so since the `write.table` command contains the parameter `append=T`, it adds to the file `results.txt`- so if you also use the parameter `col.names=T` it will enter a header each time an entry is made.... You should probably just make a `results.txt` file with text editor and just insert the headers manually before running the code.
As for having a different file for each state- you could use `paste` when specifying the output file i.e. `write.table(..., file=paste0(input_state,'_results.txt'),...)`

Comment: So there is no way of creating a new file with just the data from the start of a single experiment every time 't' is pressed to terminate the recording? I want to avoid other lab users going into the text file directly to ensure data integrity is maintained. Another thing I wondered was whether it was possible to introduce an 's' key press to start the process of recording the user input - similar to 't' to terminate but 's' to start? Then once it is running whether it would be possible to select a user state when they enter an area rather than when they leave? Apologies if this isn't clear.